# Cycle-by-cycle current limiting with latching comparator

Tags: motor-controller, comparator, current-limiting, latch

I am attempting to design a cycle-by-cycle current limiting circuit for a motor driver.

Here is my circuit along with some notes to explain its intended operation:
[image]

The latching comparator I plan on using is the [MAX9141](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX9140-MAX9144-1291701.pdf).

I am trying to ensure I'm not violating the setup and hold constraints of the latch, but the datasheet is a little vague about the exact implementation of the latch and provides this diagram:
[image]

From the above diagram, it appears the latch setup/hold constraints are dependent on the input signal into the comparator, not the output of the comparator.

In my circuit, since the latch is only being enabled once the signal has propagated to the output, I'm not sure how to bound the setup/hold conditions.

Comment: It would be a lot better to implement this in the motor driver's MCU code for the PWM peripheral if you are building the motor driver yourself. But in hardware, you are after something that releases the latch for re-triggering on an edge, not a level, which means you need a flip flop somewhere.

Comment: Controlling the ramped currents with a pulsed voltage increases duration according to the RPM generated BEMF difference voltage or reducing load. Thus you have torque control and not RPM control. This IC is a comparator sampled by the negative edge LE with it’s 16ns setup and hold times and 45ns prop delay.  But when voltage is turned off the current in the motor changes direction while your  bridge ramps down and will have some latency much greater than the setup time, so you would need to delay and XOR both PWM edges to clock this comparator create a set and reset pulse with PWM at 2f.

Comment: A window comparator would work if you want to operate in CCM with set upper current variable and lower level the amount of ripple as ratio or fixed amount using PFM that  you can handle for L/R = T time constant  to determine the clock rate.

Comment: Comparators are usually rated with some *overdrive* level, that's what your input dependency is. Work out your worst case overdrive and calculate back from that.